# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Use Angular 2 with Hybrid Mobile Application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-server, mobilefirst-studio

I am using MobileFirst Platform to build hybrid mobile application, i am doing this using AngularJS v1.4 , now i want to migrate to Angular 2.

I am using MobileFirst platform eclipse plugin's.

While using AngularJS i used to add angular.js file inside lib folder

`ProjectName/apps/AppName/common/lib/js/angular.js`

i searched for best practice in using Angular 2 within a project and i found this repository:

https://github.com/angular/quickstart

My question: What is the best practice in using Angular 2 with MFP hybrid mobile app?

- where to add all Angular 2 files such as: src folder,package.json,bs-config.json ..etc ?
- where to run `npm install` command to add node_modules folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ionic 3 to incorporate angular 2 as it will handle the build process of angular files and you can also use MFP 8 cordova plugin.

Comment: My question was if i can use angular 2 with MFP 7.1 without migrating to MFP 8

Comment: In that case use angular 2 cli and move the build files to www folder.